How to correctly install an extension on an existing Azure web app using Bicep?
I have been trying to get an extension installed correctly on an existing app service, using a bicep module shown below. The problem is, it sometimes works, and other times it will fail due to "reaching a time limit for install."
param appName string

// Resource reference
resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2023-12-01' existing = {
  name: appName
}

// Add New Relic Extension to existing web app
resource siteExtension 'Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions@2023-12-01' = {
  parent: webApp
  name: 'NewRelic.Azure.WebSites.Extension'
}

Does anyone know the correct way to install this extension where it works every time?
Thanks!

Was looking at the documentation and you need to disable app insights first and also shut down the web app: https://docs.newrelic.com/kr/install/dotnet/?deployment=azure&azure=azuresiteextension

This is because your extension needs to be downloaded from the Gallery, and the download process cannot be guaranteed to be stable. This is not a serious problem. If the extension deployment fails, try to deploy your extension multiple times separately.

Are you executing it using Az CLI? @jobatthemall

@Jahnavi Does not seem possible with an Azure CLI command: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7617

@Thomas Does that mean there is no way to install this with a bicep module? Or is that possible to include commands to shut down the web app + disable app insights in that bicep module?

@jobatthemall Deployment can be done with CLI command. How about that?

@jobatthemall, have you tried installing manually, is it wrking ?

@Thomas might you be able to help with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79288620/is-there-a-way-to-extract-the-apimuid-verfication-id-property-via-bicep-that-is


Correctly install an extension on an existing Azure web app using Bicep

Since your configuration able to install the extensions some time and failed to do the same in order cases.
Which means we need a setup which make sure the installation works as per the expectation. For this you include checkAppReady using CLI commands which make sure that webapp is ready to install extensions.
Configuration:
param appName string
param location string = resourceGroup().location


resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2021-02-01' existing = {
  name: appName
}


resource checkAppReady 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: 'checkAppReadyScript'
  location: location
  kind: 'AzureCLI'
  properties: {
    azCliVersion: '2.30.0'
    scriptContent: '''
      appState=$(az webapp show --name "${appName}" --resource-group "${resourceGroup().name}" --query "state" -o tsv)
      echo $appState
    '''
    timeout: 'PT10M'
    retentionInterval: 'P1D'
  }
}


resource siteExtension 'Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'NewRelic.Azure.WebSites.Extension'
  parent: webApp
  dependsOn: [
    checkAppReady
  ]
}

Deployment:


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2021-02-01/sites/siteextensions?pivots=deployment-language-bicep
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template
