Is there a way to extract the apimuid verfication ID property via bicep that is needed for a managed custom domain on APIM?
I need to be able to create a TXT record pointing to an APIM verification ID, I've found a way to do this with web apps, but APIM seems to not be the same. For example below I tried:
// Reference an existing APIM service
resource apim 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2024-05-01' existing = {
  name: apimServiceName
  scope: resourceGroup()
}

module txt '../network/public-txt-record.module.bicep' = {
  name: 'txtModule'
  params: {
    publicDnsZoneName: publicDnsZoneName
    txtRecordName: txtRecordName
    txtRecordValue: apim.properties.customProperties
  }
}

However, where ".customProperties" is there does not seem to be a property called "custom domain verification ID" like there is for web apps.
Is there another way to dynamically extract this property from existing APIM resources in order to create the TXT records and add custom domains to the APIM resources?
Thanks!

Are you looking for only bicep approach?

@Jahnavi yes I posted a reply to your first answer below, thanks!

To extract the verification ID property from existing APIM resources in order to create the TXT records, you need to extract the hostname configuration directly from the properties rather than trying with custom properties.
apim.properties.hostnameConfigurations[0].hostName

Complete code:
param apimname string = 'newapimjahsd'
resource apim 'Microsoft.ApiManagement/service@2023-05-01-preview' existing = {
 name: apimname
}
output txtrecordvalue string = apim.properties.hostnameConfigurations[0].hostName


Note: You can change the hostnameConfigurations indices if you have one or more custom domains.
Refer SO for the similar information.

Hello, apim.properties.hostnameConfigurations[0].hostName does not seem to output the correct verification ID needed though. In this instance this would be taking place right after creation, so the first custom domain being added. It looks like this in the portal if this helps clarify: https://imgur.com/a/WEKqThP

Can you elaborate it for better understanding! Are you looking for a managed custom domain creation as well? @jobatthemall

Yes, that's correct. Managed custom domain and managed cert creation need to be handled within bicep. I have found a way to do this, but only if that TXT record is manually created before running the bicep deployment. I need to add a TXT record creation module that creates a TXT record with a value of the record being the verification id shown here: https://imgur.com/a/WEKqThP It needs to be pulled dynamically though, but that doesn't seem possible.

Yes dynamically pulling the value for TXT creation doesn't possible as far as I know. Anyways I will check again and update ypu. @jobatthemall
